Nowadays, how similar is Duolingo to a gacha game?
Gacha games are known for ethically dubious monetization practices (see this video).

They're free to play games, but you can make in-game purchases;
They're designed to be easy;
They're deliberately designed to be habit-forming and even addictive, such as by applying pressure through FOMO, sunk cost (the IKEA effect), time gates, etc.;
"Whales" might spend $1000+ on games, while most people spend nothing;
In-game purchases solve problems, but those problems are built into the game by the manufacturers;
Children can play them;
There's elements of gambling (like loot boxes);
Some are basically play-to-win (despite being advertised as free-to-play).

I also note that currently Duolingo is doing a collaboration with gacha game Genshin Impact.
While it's clear Duolingo has some of the aforementioned mechanics, I don't know enough about how Duolingo is currently monetized to appraise how similar it is to a gacha game.
Question: Nowadays, how similar is Duolingo to a gacha game?

I’m not sure what this has to do with learning a language? If you have a complaint with the app (which it sounds like you might), you could take it up with the dev team.
